# как заменить роль другому пользователю?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, замена

мне нужно чтобы одна роль забралась , а другая добавилась ( НЕ АВТОРУ КОМАНДЫ )
через команду " replace (имя пользователя) "

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы заменить роль пользователю через `Discord.py`, вам нужно сначала получить объект роли, которую хотите дать пользователю, а затем использовать метод `discord.Member.add_roles()` для добавления роли к пользователю. Вы также можете использовать метод `discord.Member.remove_roles()` для удаления роли у пользователя. Ниже приведен пример кода, который делает это:

```
@client.command()
async def replace(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    # Удаляем роль у пользователя
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    # Добавляем новую роль пользователю
    await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Название новой роли"))
```

В этом примере `client` - это экземпляр класса `discord.Client`, `ctx` - это объект контекста, а `user` и `role` - это объекты `discord.Member` и `discord.Role` соответственно, переданные в качестве аргументов команды. В этом примере мы удаляем роль `role` у пользователя `user`, а затем добавляем название новой роли, которую хотите дать пользователю, вместо того, чтобы указывать ее название явно, мы используем утилиту `discord.utils.get()` для получения роли с заданным именем. Это позволяет избежать проблемы с тем, что роль может быть записана с ошибками в каком-то регистре.

Чтобы использовать эту команду, вы должны вызвать ее с указанием имени пользователя (или его ID) и названия роли (или ее ID) в качестве аргументов. Например:

```
!replace @User#1234 Название роли
```

Обратите внимание, что вы должны иметь разрешение на изменение ролей для того, чтобы использовать эту команду. В противном случае вам будет выдана ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def replace(ctx, member:  discord.Member):
     await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id="айди роли"))
     await member.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id="айди второй роли"))
     await ctx.reply("Успешно!")
```

Вроде так

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]